# can't get form access from my class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@private
    IBOutlet NSTextField *tf;
}
- (void)setStr;

@end

===========================================

#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setStr
{
    [tf setStringValue:@"aaaaaaaaa"];
}

@end
```

Call a method from my AppDelegate class

```
- (IBAction)test1:(id)sender
{
     MyClass *m = [[MyClass alloc] init];
     [m setStr];
}
```

I created an object of MyClass in .xib file. I correlated outlet of textfield with a textfield on form.
And there are no actions when button pressed.
where I'm wrong?

Comment: When you say XIB file, I believe you meant a view.

Comment: your creating second object for the same class.one is from appdelegate and another is within the class and your asking textfeild text then you have to mention UITextfeild if it is cocoatouch..

Comment: @user210504, I don't think that's what he meant. I think he has an instance of MyClass in his XIB file, and therefore in his NIB at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an outlet for MyClass in AppDelegate and connect it up, then use that outlet in test1 instead of creating a new instance. This [guide from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/06Controller/06Controller.html) should help you.

Another possibility is to put the `test1` action into `MyClass` and have it called directly with the button press, or to make `setStr` an IBAction. These are possible, since you have a `MyClass` instance in your XIB.

Comment: "You need to create an outlet for MyClass in AppDelegate and connect it up, then use that outlet in test1 instead of creating a new instance." .. please tell me how to do this?

Comment: The same way you created `IBOutlet NSTextField *tf;`. The `MyClass` instance sitting in your XIB is the same as an object sitting inside a window. I updated my answer with a link that may help you.